# In Unix shell, how to Check user's permission ,if the user doesn't have, how to produce an error message?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I was trying to write a script which will be able to perform some build-in command ,such as : cp, rm, ls or whatever.
The menu might be like this:

1. list the current directory
2. Rename a file
3. Remove a file
4. exit

when you executed that some commands like "ls -la $currentdirectory"
which will show almost all the information of the current directory.

SO:  if the user does not have permission to do that, (the user doesn't have permission to "LS" that directory .

what command can check the permission?
How to produce an error message if that user does not  have the permission?
Cheers
hope to get that answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any separate command to figure out permissions on a directory/file. `ls` itself will output an error kinda message.

For example, I take away all permissions from everyone,

```
chmod 000 some_folder
ls some_folder/
ls: some_folder/: The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.
```

*Most* commands in Unix like systems will automatically error out with an error message if they don't have sufficient permissions to do their job! The underlying framework will take care of not allowing under-privileged users/apps to run.

Comment: I think you miss my another question:How to produce an error message if that user does not have the permission? I just wanted to write a script which can handle that error if that error occurs

Comment: @user1383819 You are missing the point. The commands themselves will produce an error as shown in the answer above. To check whether the previous command error-ed out, you can check the value of `$?` from inside your shell script

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -i umask ~/.profile /etc/profile
```